# How to add multiple views as a single View to a GridLayout in Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

So I have a `GridLayout` that I want to display both, `ImageView` & `TextView` in each of its cells. Each `TextView` should be placed right under the `ImageView` in the Grid cell.

Problem here is, a `GridLayout` only accepts a single View for each addition, unlike `GridView` where an `Adapter` does the job.

Please note that I cannot use `GridView` here as there's a constraint to restrict the number of Rows, so `GridView` is not an option for me.

I was wondering if there was any way in which I could create a custom view that would contain two different views within & add it to the `GridLayout`.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a custom view.

Create an XML layout file in res/layout with the layout you want for the view (most likely a vertical `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and `TextView`).

Then create a class for your custom view which inflates the layout.

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(inflater != null){       
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this);         
        }
    }
}
```

Then this can be accessed in your `GridLayout` as follows:

```
<GridLayout>
    <com.yourpackage.CustomView android:id="@+id\id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.yourpackage.CustomView>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would use RecyclerView with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html).

You can set it:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

where the number indicates the row count.
For every item in the RecyclerView you can have custom layout (as in all adapters), which don't need to be single View

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can create your own View.

First you need to create your layout file that could look like this

my_linear_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="New Text"
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you create your own class for this view and inflate it

MyView.java

```
package com.example.stack.test38526476;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView text;
    private ImageView image;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_linear_layout, this);
        this.text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use it in your GridLayout

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stack.test38526476.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <com.example.stack.test38526476.MyView/>

        <com.example.stack.test38526476.MyView/>

        <com.example.stack.test38526476.MyView/>

    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why `<com.example.stack.test38526476.MyView/>` three times?